# Create shared folder on sdcard

Tags: external-sd, file-permissions, termux

Is there any way to create a directory on an external sdcard that has read/write access for multiple apps. For example I want to us synththing or rsync under termux be able to sync this directory to my file server. I also want to be able to download music from a browser or other app and add it to the directory, which would then be synced with the file server.

I am using an Android k7 with android 5.1.1

My phone is not rooted and I would rather not root it unless I have to.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
termux-setup-storage
```

And create anything you want in `~/storage/shared` (which is a symlink to `/sdcard`.

Comment: On my phone sdcard is syslinked to /storage/emulated/legacy which is on the internal storage not the external sdcard.

Comment: @Samuel The app's data folder on the external SD is available as `~/storage/external-1`, which points to `/storage/{hash}/Android/data/com.termux/files`. Any other location of the card is restricted.

Comment: is there any way to create a non-restricted folder?

Comment: I see there is a /storage/shared under termux can something like that be made on the sdcard